# Here API token expires in 24 hours

Tags: here-api

I wish to use the here api in an app but the credential for calling the api expires in 24 hours

is there any other alternative long term solution that doesnt require client side refresh of the token every time the user wants to use the API ?

https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html#using-postman

I want to use the GeoCode API to get city and lat/lng results https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-geocode-brief.html

Answer (score 2):

here doesn't make it very clear, but the reason the API key expires after 24h, is because you haven't confirmed your email address yet. Once you confirmed the email, it shouldn't expire anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since here maps user can have 2 active tokens at a time, you can write a service to refresh these tokens at an interval of 12 hrs and this service will provide you recently activated token so that client always get an active.

Answer (score -1):

You can get an API key and then do:

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=5+Rue+Daunou%2C+75000+Paris%2C+France&apiKey=YOURAPIKEY
```

You can sign up for a free account [here](https://developer.here.com/sign-up?create=Freemium-Basic&keepState=true&step=account).